# Finding the probability of students learning material within a certain timeframe

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I am trying to determine the probability of students learning a set of instructions within a given period of time. The length of time it takes for the students to learn has a normal distribution with a mean of 24min and a standard deviation of 8min. There is only one copy of the instructions, so as soon as one person has completed the learning process, the next person begins, with no intervening gap. What is the probability that the total time for 25 learners to complete the process will be less than 9 hours (i.e. 540 minutes)?

I first wrote the probability for a single learner:

540/25=21.6min

p(x<21.6) = p((x-μ)/(σ/√n)<(21.6-24)/(8/√25)

Using normal approximation:

p(z<-1.5)

=p(z>1.5)

=0.066807

Does this check out?

Comment: It looks as if you may be trying to find the distribution of the _average_ of the 25 times, not their _total._  // One _could_ do it that way, but then the time limit 540 would have to be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_i,$ for  $i =1,2, \dots, 25,$ are a random sample from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 24, \sigma = 8),$ then
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{25} X_i \sim 
\mathsf{Norm}(25\mu = 600, \sqrt{25\sigma^2}= 40),$$
by independence.

You seek $P(S < 540) = 0.1587.$ Computation in R below or by standardizing and using printed normal CDF tables.

```
pnorm(540, 600, 40)
[1] 0.0668072
```

---

A simulation gives an approximate verification and a figure. [Using 100,000 iterations gives about two or three
significant digits of accuracy.]

```
set.seed(2020)
s = replicate(10^5, sum(rnorm(25, 24, 8)))
mean(s); sd(s)
[1] 599.9223   # aprx E(S) = 600
[1] 39.87919   # aprx SD(S) = 40
mean(s < 540)   
[1] 0.06765    # aprx P(S < 540) = 0.0668

hist(s, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2",
     main="Simulated Totals")
 curve(dnorm(x,600,40), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
 abline(v = 540, lty="dotted", lwd=3, col="darkgreen")
```

[image]